# How to display in the view edit-add.blade.php only some tables in Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

It's my first time using blade and I'm a little confused with this. I need to show a form like what it comes with the default edit-add view in Voyager, but I need to display some inputs based on roles. I am filtering by the current user that is logged in and that is working fine, but I need to hide/display some inputs of the form based on that.

How can I accomplish this in the blade view?

Here is how Voyager take the data in the blade view:

```
@php
$dataTypeRows = $dataType->{(isset($dataTypeContent->id) ? 'editRows' :'addRows' )};
@endphp

@foreach($dataTypeRows as $row)
    <!-- GET THE DISPLAY OPTIONS -->
    @php
        $options = json_decode($row->details);
        $display_options = isset($options->display) ? $options->display : NULL;
    @endphp
    @if ($options && isset($options->formfields_custom))
        @include('voyager::formfields.custom.' . $options->formfields_custom)
    @else
        <div class="form-group @if($row->type == 'hidden') hidden @endif @if(isset($display_options->width)){{ 'col-md-' . $display_options->width }}@else{{ '' }}@endif" @if(isset($display_options->id)){{ "id=$display_options->id" }}@endif>
            {{ $row->slugify }}
            <label for="name">{{ $row->display_name }}</label>
            @include('voyager::multilingual.input-hidden-bread-edit-add')
            @if($row->type == 'relationship')
                @include('voyager::formfields.relationship')
            @else
                {!! app('voyager')->formField($row, $dataType, $dataTypeContent) !!}
            @endif

            @foreach (app('voyager')->afterFormFields($row, $dataType, $dataTypeContent) as $after)
                {!! $after->handle($row, $dataType, $dataTypeContent) !!}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

If my table 'example' contains: id, name, address and phone. How do I display in this view form only inputs for name and address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = Example::find($id);
    return view(‘viewname’,compact(‘user’));
}

edit-add.blade.php
<input type = “text” name=”name” value=”@if(isset($user->name)){{ old('name', $user->name) }}@else{{old('name')}}@endif”>

<input type = “text” name=”name” value=”@if(isset($user->address)){{ old('address', $user->address) }}@else{{old('address')}}@endif”>
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant understand what do you mean but
for showing a value in input in a view first you should send the value to view for example in controller you have :

```
public function test()
{
  .....
  return view('myView',compact('user'));
}
```

then in your view :

```
<input type="text" value"{{$user->address}}">
<input type="text" value"{{$user->first_name}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it from ADMIN interface without using any code
Just go to the settings  menu and click BREAD